# Why is svg generated by MathJax.js different than the svg generated by MathJax-node

Tags: mathjax

I am writing an web app that saves html to onenote. In order to save math formulas, I plan to convert math formulas to svg by MathJax.js and then convert svg to png, because the html/css supported in onenote api is limited.

But it seems the svg generated by MathJax.js in browser is not a valid svg. I tested it with a simple math formula: `$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$` ([demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/xkf9bjxw/)) and copy the svg to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkzvtzos/) and it displays nothing.

Then I tried to write a MathJax-node demo and copy the svg to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz51zcfn/) again, it looks good. Here is my demo code, it's almost the same as the [GitHub repo demo](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node#getting-started):

```
// a simple TeX-input example
const fs = require('fs')
var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node");
mjAPI.config({
  MathJax: {
    // traditional MathJax configuration
  }
});
mjAPI.start();

var yourMath = String.raw`a^2 + b^2 = c^2`

mjAPI.typeset({
  math: yourMath,
  format: "TeX", // or "inline-TeX", "MathML"
  svg: true,      // or svg:true, or html:true
}, function (data) {
  if (!data.errors) {console.log(data.svg)}
  // will produce:
  // <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  //   <mi>E</mi>
  //   <mo>=</mo>
  //   <mi>m</mi>
  //   <msup>
  //     <mi>c</mi>
  //     <mn>2</mn>
  //   </msup>
  // </math>

  fs.writeFile('math.txt', data.svg, (error) => {
      console.log(error)
  })
});
```

I also tested two svg with [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png), it's the same result. Why are the two svg different? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is due to a specific setting: `useGlobalCache`

By default, MathJax ([docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/SVG.html)) sets this to `true` while mathjax-node ([docs](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node#typesetoptions-callback)) sets this to `false`.

On the server MathJax-node does not have any document context and produces self-contained SVGs. On the client, MathJax has a full document context and thus can re-use the SVG paths across equations.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. It's a bit tricky since mathjax-node has a peculiar history. MathJax v3 (nearing its first beta release) will unify both so these kinds of things will be easier in the future.